# How to send route from browser to another device?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

my application forming route uses google.map api , and i want to send this route to car or phone\tablet, possibility by Google account(e-mail), via button using javascript;
`service.route` like this:

```
    service.route({
    origin: officeLocation,
    destination: officeLocation,
    waypoints: clientAdrArray,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidTolls: true
}, function (response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        display.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        alert('ERROR: ' + status);
    }
});
```

P.s. button like this, but programmatically
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send data from your application to clients you have to use a server,
or use Backend as a service product like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or [Backand](https://www.backand.com).